# greasemonkey - run script when html and css is loaded

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, greasemonkey-4

As the title says, I want to wait until the html is parsed, and all stylesheets are loaded, because I need to use `currentsyle`. However, I *do not* want to wait for images. So I cannot use `load` event, as that waits for images. And I can't use the `DOMContentLoaded` event, as that doesn't wait for stylesheets. I also cannot use `document.body.appendChild` to add a script tag at the end of the document because this script is being run under the assumption that javascript on the page is disabled.

Is there seriously no event to wait on styles?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three possibly `run-at` values for GM scripts - with corresponding document.readyState in brackets

- document-start (**before** `document.readyState === 'loading'`)
- document-end (`document.readyState === 'ineractive'`)
- document-idle (`document.readyState === 'complete'`)

These are the only available injection points for your script

at start/end - no external resources will be loaded yet, so too early for what you want

at idle, all external resources are loaded, so too late for what you want

OK, you know all this, but I'm adding it for other future readers

if you load your script at document-end, you can add `load` listeners to all `<link rel="stylesheet"` like

```
Promise.all(Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('link[rel="stylesheet"]'), ss => new Promise(resolve => {
    const href = ss.href;
    const fulfill = status => resolve({href, status});
    setTimeout(fulfill, 5000, 'timeout');
    ss.addEventListener('load', () => resolve('load'));
    ss.addEventListener('error', () => resolve('error')); // yes, resolve, because we just want to wait until all stylesheets are done with, errors shouldn't stop us
}))).then((results) => {
    // results is an array of {href:'some url', status: 'load|error|timeout'}
    // at this point stylesheets have finished loading
});
```

Comment: This is a pretty elegant solution. However, it doesn't run if the script runs after a stylesheet has loaded or failed to load. I tested a case where stylesheets are being blocked by uMatrix, and it won't run in that case because the stylesheets are blocked before the user script is run. Is there a way to check if a stylesheet has failed to load or finished loading?

Comment: what about `setTimeout` - see edited code @user234683

Comment: @user234683 - I've edited the code a bit, so in the `.then` you can iterate through results to see what loaded and what didn't - perhaps useful for *development* phase of your userscript

Comment: My userscript runs on all websites, so I can't make any assumptions about the stylesheets. I guess a timeout will have to do sadly. I'll mark this as the answer in a few days if no one else comes along with ideas for detecting if a stylesheet failed to load.

Comment: I would've thought that a failure should trigger an error event - or even a timeout event - what do you see in the console when one of these stylesheets fail?

Comment: The problem isn't that an error event isn't being triggered. The problem is that the userscript begins running after such error events happen. It seems the external stylesheet blocking isn't being logged in the console, only external javascript. It is logged to the umatrix logger, however, which gives the time as HH:MM:SS. If I print the time at the beginning of the userscript to the console, I find that the userscript starts in the second after the stylesheets are blocked (So the stylesheets are blocked at 3:43:36 and the userscript starts at 3:43:37)